# Cannot import Eclipse project into Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying to import an Android project build on Eclipse into my Android Studio IDE. I'm following the steps to import properly the project with a build.gradle file but when I'm trying to compile, I get this weird error:  Plugin with id 'android' not found. I have this version of Android Studio: Android Studio (Preview) 0.4.3. Here is my build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile project(':workspace:DesignDialogLibrary')
compile project(':workspace:HoloColorPickerLib')
compile project(':workspace:MbAdBleamSdkReaderLibrary')
compile project(':workspace:ViewPagerLibrary')
compile project(':workspace:PullToRefreshLibrary')
compile project(':workspace:SlidingMenuLib')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing this block in your **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
```

This block tells Gradle where to find the "android" plugin that you're missing.

It's standard in projects created in newer versions of Android Studio to put this in the **build.gradle** that's in your project's root directory and omit it from the one that's in your module's directory, so look there and see if looks like it's in order.

If you don't have that root-level **build.gradle** file and you've only got one directory and one build file, then add this block to that file. Be aware, however, that Android Studio currently has a few bugs that prevent the Project Structure dialog from working properly with projects in this single-module format, though I believe they'll otherwise build and run fine.

Comment: Just one think I have some external Android JAVA project and I would like to add it to my main project with my build.gradle like this:  compile project(':workspace:DesignDialogLibrary') But Android Studio always tell me 'Project with path :workspace:DesignDialogLibrary' cannot be found in the root project.

Comment: You need a multi-project (aka multi-moudle) setup, and you have to define all your modules in a settings.gradle file. See the docs at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-project-setup and post a separate question if you're having problems getting it working.